# Making list inside list from loop

Tags: python

In this code here:

```
dotted_map = []
for row in range(3):
    dotted_map.append("".join(list(2*'o ' + 'o')))
print(dotted_map)
```

It is printing

```
['o o o', 'o o o', 'o o o']
```

I want it to print this:

```
[['o o o'], ['o o o'], ['o o o']]
```

Why is it not doing that?

Comment: You're appending a string to the list, not a list with a string in it. Try `dotted_map.append(["".join(list(2*'o ' + 'o'))])`

Comment: Thank you, this works, but what is the list() function even doing in that case? I took it off and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, all you really need is `dotted_map.append([2*'o ' + 'o'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you just have to do it this way

```
dotted_map.append([2*'o ' + 'o'])
```

In your way, the `list()` method makes it into a list, but then the `join()` method, converts the list back into a string.

```
2*'o ' + 'o' # is a string 'o o o'
list(2*'o ' + 'o') # is a list ['o o o']
"".join(list(2*'o ' + 'o')) # is a string again 'o o o'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nick, you need to add square brackets for it to work.

```
dotted_map.append(["".join(list(2*'o ' + 'o'))])
```